# How does scoping works in for loop? let and undefined

Tags: javascript

My for loop has 5 different scenarios

```js
function likes(names) {
    const n = names.length;
    const n2 = (n - 2).toString();
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let result;
        if (n === 0) {
            result = 'no one likes this';
        } else if (n === 1) {
            result = `${names[0]} likes this`;
        } else if (n === 2) {
            result = `${names[0]} and ${names[1]} like this`;
        } else if (n === 3) {
            result = `${names[0]} ,${names[1]} and ${names[2]} like this`;
        } else {
            result = `${names[0]} ,${names[1]} and ${n2} others like this`;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
console.log(likes([]));
```

My program works fine for all except the first one.

```
console.log(likes([]));
```

shows

```
undefined
```

Why?

Comment: Why do you have `likes[]`? Why is the squared bracets empty?

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't compile, it looks like it isn't complete. You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: @BudaÖrs function likes[].

Comment: @Quentin I edited post,function was added.

Comment: because you have written return statement in for loop and n = 0 so it won't go inside loop

Comment: Why have you written a `for` loop? You can just return a result based on the amount of names, there's no need to loop over it.

Comment: Additionally to Quentin's answer, you don't need the loop at all. The if conditions are doing the job already, `i` is never used anywhere.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913027/trying-to-use-a-for-loop-with-if-else-statement-in-objects/41913039#41913039

Comment: @Teemu Yeah,works without loop as expected.

Comment: If you want to get a correct sentence without a ton of ifs, you can put the texts in a table, and pick a correct index, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/h3xu8a49/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `names` is an empty array, then the end condition for the `for` loop is met before the loop is ever entered.

Consequently the loop is *never* entered so the `return` statement inside the loop is never reached.

A function which doesn't evaluate a `return` statement returns `undefined`.